# How to get a file out of a compiled unity game that I made

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a mini game using Unity and built it a few months back. It was just a pet project so I deleted the project file but still have the built/compiled game. In the project's ASSETS, I put a text file with some notes that I had created for myself and some scripts.

Is there a way to extract or even just see the text file from my built game? Is there a way to extract all the assets or something?

I'm extremely new at this kind of thing so unfortunately, I don't really know the right way to ask the question or find it on google. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## Probably not

That text file, if it wasn't used as an asset, isn't going to be in your compiled game anyway. But even if it *was,* finding it and extracting it would be difficult due to the semi-obfuscated nature of dlls and how Unity compresses and builds assets into dlls.

Comment: I heavily doubt that unity compiles assets into quote-on-quote DLLs

Comment: @IsaacCarolWeisberg The phrase is ["quote-unquote"](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/26114-What-does-quot-Quote-on-Quote-quot-mean) and you have the `"` available in text, making the phrase completely unnecessary. The *point is* that assets are not in a readily locatable place in an easy to read format. They're compressed and serialized in a custom manner, *and that assumes that the text file was treated as an asset in the first place.* Someone [wrote an extraction tool](https://forum.xentax.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=10085) but the file is not available, so I can't try it out.

Comment: Yeah, I just meant that these archives are not necessarily dynamically linkable Windows NT libraries, nor do these archives have a `.dll` extension-- so

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the file accessible post-build by design, use [StreamingAssets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) folder.
Otherwise you'll have to rely on 'uglier' methods as mentioned by Draco18s (people steal assets all the time so it's not impossible).

Answer (score 0):

what's your building platform ? 
if it's android then you can get a look at the scripts and other text files using ILSpy.

Just change the .apk to .zip
Unzip, and open the compiled files in ILSPY.